# Angular material 2 preselect mat-table rows

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to preselect rows with angular material table. There is `initialSelection` in `SelectionModel` see [example](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/table/table.md#1-add-a-selection-model). But there is no exact explanation how it works. Is it possible to use this initialSelection to make some rows preselected?

---

#### Edit 1:

It looks like, that `initialSelection` needs to be subset of data array passed as `dataSource` to `mat-table`. It is working now.

#### Edit 2:

[Updated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyvxbr) offical example. Look at `app/table-selection-example.ts` lines `21 - 25`

```
  subSet1 = this.dataSource.data.slice(0,2);
  subSet2 = this.dataSource.data.slice(3,5);
  preselectExample = this.subSet1.concat(this.subSet2);

  selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, this.preselectExample);
```

Comment: Hey @TomP, Have you got any idea on this? I'm looking for the same example.

Comment: @NikunjPatel i updated my post ... hope u will understand

Comment: Nice @TomP, That's working great. My selection list is getting empty when I rebind table. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: initialSelection = [];
selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, this.initialSelection);
private ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [];
private dataSourceProviders = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
private displayedColumns;
loadOtherUsers() {
        this.userService.getAll('np').subscribe(data => {
            this.displayedColumns = ['select', 'name'];
            this.ELEMENT_DATA = data;
            this.dataSourceProviders = new MatTableDataSource(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
        });
    }

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz example ?

Comment: Please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045049/selection-list-become-empty-when-datasource-is-updated-datatable-materil2/49054722#49054722

Answer (score 1):

So, after a long battle with table and lots of selections I did it a bit better than slicing and dicing the array.

```
this.initialSelection = this.data.filter((element,e) => {
     return this.savedSelection.some( (val,i) => { 
         if(element.key === val.key) { 
             this.data[e]['amount'] = val['amount']; 
             return true;
         }
     return;
  });
});
this.dataSource.data = this.data;
this.selection = new SelectionModel<any>(true, this.initialSelection);
```

there's also an extra for editable values and later asign values back to the table for the ones that are selected.

Cheers.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-urd5c4